# How to acquire current values in data acquisiton accurately when using a shunt resistor in a current loop?

Tags: current-measurement, shunt, 4-20ma

Here is the setup I use.

[image]

Since the DAQ system is only able to read voltages first I record the voltages by a shunt resistor. But I need the "current values" at the end. Transducer will make the current vary between 4 to 20 mA.

If the resistance is constant with respect to current one could just divide the voltage readings to resistance and obtain the current in the loop.

But I observed that the resistance is not the same for different currents. For example for a constant applied 20mA current the resistance is 248.74ohm and for 4 mA 248.27ohm. Is it better in that case to obtain a calibration expression (current to voltage) and calculate the currents in that way instead of taking the resistance a constant?

Comment: How sensitive is your measurement to these errors? What are your other system errors? You're talking about a 0.2% error between 4 and 20mA - that is already extremely good for an uncalibrated system.

Comment: i obtain a current voltage line. my question is should i use this line to calculate the currents from voltage readings or should i choose a constant resistance value? which is more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 20 mA the resistor will be dissipating more power than at 4 mA. Say the resistor is 250 ohm (as per your previous question [How to achieve common ground for a single ended input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90121/how-to-achieve-common-ground-for-a-single-ended-input)), the power will be 100 mW at 20mA whereas at 4 mA the power will only be 4 mW.

If your resistor warms up 10 ºC and is a 25ppm/ºC type the resistance change will be from 250 ohm to 250.06 ohms or down to 249.94 ohms.

If your resistor warms up 20 ºC and it is a 50ppm/ºC type the resistance will change from 250 ohm to 250.25 ohms or down to 249.75 ohms.

This seems around the same order as what you are measuring. I calculate a change in resistance of 0.47 ohms - could this be due to self-heating?

Comment: I obtain that line(current input - voltage output) with 2 measurements i.e. for 4mA and 20mA constant current. 
I obtain a line because I dont have another measurement point. My constant current source outputs only 4 and 20mA.
I obtain the calibration expression (current-voltage) as linear but Im not sure it should be linear in real since I can only measure at 2 steps.

Comment: Precisely what is the make and model of your resistor - let's get to the heart of the problem. Did yesterday's advice on the previous question help?

Comment: the point is the resistor has no color code. it is totally black. i have no data sheet. thats why i try this method. some engineer before be measured it as 249.5 something 2 years ago. but they want me to use this resistance. so thats why im measuring again

Comment: The error you get is likely to be this - without a spec you are in the dark. Get a resistor like this one: http://uk.farnell.com/vishay-foil-resistors-vpg/1625250r000t9r/resistor-precision-250r-1206/dp/1109038 it is 0.01% and has a temperature coefficient of 0.2ppm per ºC or maybe something a bit less expensive. The error you are getting can easily be down to the resistor or maybe the offset voltage drift of your amplifier. Did the info I gave yesterday help? If so please consider accepting the answer or upvoting it. This site favours those who show some form of appreciation for useful advice.

Comment: it didnt help much because im not getting clear answers to my questions. i have to use this resistor. thanks for ideas anyway. my question was is that better to calibrate versus current or take resistance as  a constant. im asking which is more accurate. i cant change the setup unforunately not in my control